# Улучшить регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Всем добрый день!
Изучаю программирование, а также являюсь сериаломаном и возникла задача автоматизировать скачку сериалов через торрент клиент (qbittorrent).
В данном клиенте есть RSS загрузчик к которому фильтры пишутся через регулярные выражения.
Дано:
RSS feed lostilm'a.
( К примеру сериал сверхъестественное, который содержит следующие названия торрентов:

- Сверхъестественное (Supernatural). Горсточка счастливцев (We Happy
  Few). (S11E22)
- Сверхъестественное (Supernatural). Горсточка счастливцев (We Happy
  Few) [1080p]. (S11E22)
- Сверхъестественное (Supernatural). Горсточка счастливцев (We Happy
  Few) [MP4]. (S11E22))

Написана регулярка для поиска сериала качеством 1080р:

```
Сверхъестественное\s\(\w+\)\.\s\D+\s\[1080p\]
```

Данная регулярка работает и с lotstilm'a будет скачивать любой сериал, но мне кажется, что её можно улучшить, но т.к. я особо не писал на регулярках ( знаю основы только) мне кажется, что можно написать лучше. 
Укажите как это можно сделать лучше.

Comment: Сверхъестественное.*\\[1080p\\]

Comment: Так просто, а я извращался, спасибо.

Comment: Понять бы ещё, почему regex101.com захватывает символ после скобок — https://regex101.com/r/cZ7lD0/1 .

Comment: Странно у меня все ок. https://regex101.com/r/bH9uP6/1

Comment: @rjhdby оформьте, как ответ, пожалуйста

Comment: Константин, прошу прощения, сейчас тестировал на разных браузерах — видимо, только в моём (Pale Moon) такой баг: при определённой ширине `<textarea>` [**не всегда корректно работает подсветка**](https://i.gyazo.com/367dcf49bf65aa5712545e8bce4c85d5.png) при переносе строк. Спасибо.

Comment: @ReinRaus, Вы сами сколько баллов репутации недополучаете из-за того, что не переносите комментарий в ответ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно упростить регулярное выражение до такого:

```
Сверхъестественное.*\[1080p\]
```